# Comparing length of paths

Tags: java, path

I'm trying to keep only closest paths, I made code count occurrence of slashes and I got the result:

```
html/body/div/header/div/div/a/span = 7
html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2 = 11
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a = 11
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1 = 12
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span = 11
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/h1 = 12
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/a/span/h1 = 13
```

I want by the end keep only paths which are near of each others, it must return something like this:

```
html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2 = 11
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a = 11
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1 = 12
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span = 11
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/h1 = 12
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/a/span/h1 = 13
```

I start with this Java code:

```
ArrayList<String> list_input = new ArrayList();
        list_input.add("");

        list_input.add("html/body/div/header/div/div/a/span");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/h1");
        list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/a/span/h1");

        for (int i = 0; i < list_input.size(); i++) {
            String line = (String) list_input.get(i);

            int count_nodes = line.length() - line.replace("/", "").length();
            System.out.println(line + " = " + count_nodes);

        }
```

Would someone help me to achieve this result?

Comment: Which result? ("it must return something like this" is not a very accurate description) And how is your current result different from that? Where do you think that the problem is?

Comment: i havnt problem until now , iwant just know how can i get only nearest paths

Comment: Define "nearest paths". There is nothing regular in the list of paths that you consider nearest, except that their lengths are within 2 from each other.

Comment: i think it should count differences , and then get only result of diff less than 0 or 1 or 2 and then delete paths wich is far

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to count:

```
String[] temp = line.split("/");
int count = temp.length;
```

Edited:

```
String line = (String)list_input.get(0);
int min = line.split("/").length;

for (int i = 1; i < list_input.size(); i++) {
    String line = (String)list_input.get(i);

    int count = line.split("/").length;
    if (count < min)
        min = count;
}
```

Comment: i did but , this the problem , is comparing lenght of each path with others and save only nearest ones .

Comment: Edited, take a look.

Comment: If you already have some path, take for min the difference between the "the path" and the first in arraylist, then compare the differences

Comment: ok thanks gregory i'll modify ur code to be adaptable to my case :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String str: list_input){
            System.out.println(str.split("/").length);
}
```